# How to export helm charts from AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I'm new at Kubernetes. I want to know that can we export a helm charts from a Kubernetes service? Then I want to use that helm chart to deploy another AKS.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer this [section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-helm-repos#export-helm-chart) of the document to know more details. Example to Export Helm chart:

```
helm chart export mycontainerregistry.azurecr.io/helm/hello-world:v1 \
  --destination ./install
```